# Program exits cleanly, but kubernetes is in a CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes

I created a Go client that connects to a server, rpc exchange, log and exit.  Deploying in kubernetes, I expected this to move from "*`Running -> Completed -> Running`*" loop, similar to how [dnsutils](https://kubernetes.io/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml) is deployed with a "sleep 3600" command to run for an hour and exit.

I reduced this to the smallest go program to make sure that no complexity intrudes, and this is:

```
k8s-tester ➜ cat client.go
package main   
func main() {
    return
}
```

When I this though, I actually see it go through "*`Running -> Completed -> CrashLoopBackOff -> Running`*" states.

Q:  **Why is kubernetes seeing this program as crashed when it, when run from the shell, shows an exit status of 0 (EXIT_SUCCESS)?**

> ```
>   k8s-tester ➜ kubectl create deployment --image kvaradha/client test-client
>   deployment.apps/test-client created
>   k8s-tester ➜ kubectl get pods -w -o wide
>   NAME                                  READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
>   hello-world-server-85486b969b-x744z   1/1     Running     0          10h   10.1.0.159   docker-desktop              
>   linux-544887f4fb-gksd8                1/1     Running     12         14h   10.1.0.156   docker-desktop              
>   postgres-57944b47cb-2cqtk             1/1     Running     0          13d   10.1.0.136   docker-desktop              
>   test-client-74cddbb988-rxx8f          0/1     Completed   1          4s    10.1.0.169   docker-desktop              
>   test-client-74cddbb988-rxx8f          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          5s    10.1.0.169   docker-desktop              
>   test-client-74cddbb988-rxx8f          0/1     Completed          2          21s   10.1.0.169   docker-desktop              
>   test-client-74cddbb988-rxx8f          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2          33s   10.1.0.169   docker-desktop              
>   test-client-74cddbb988-rxx8f          0/1     Completed          3          50s   10.1.0.169   docker-desktop              
>   test-client-74cddbb988-rxx8f          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          62s   10.1.0.169   docker-desktop
> ```

More details:

Simple Dockerfile that I used:

```
FROM scratch
MAINTAINER "kannan@ieee.org"
ARG  ARCH
COPY client /client
ENTRYPOINT [ "/client" ]
```

Build and deploy as:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o client .
docker build -t kvaradha/client .
kubectl create deployment --image kvaradha/client test-client
```

---

Output of docker, suggested by @sfrehse:

`k8s-tester ➜ docker run --rm kvaradha/client
2020/02/28 21:33:17 hostname: 127.0.0.1:65432 name: H809430
k8s-tester ➜ echo $?
0`

---

@CurtisMatton:  describing the pod gets me:

> `Events:
>     Type     Reason     Age                 From                     Message
>     ----     ------     ----                ----                     -------
>     Normal   Scheduled  2m2s                default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/test-client-74cddbb988-jmxmd to docker-desktop
>     Warning  Failed     110s                kubelet, docker-desktop  Failed to pull image "kvaradha/client": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
>     Warning  Failed     110s                kubelet, docker-desktop  Error: ErrImagePull
>     Normal   BackOff    109s                kubelet, docker-desktop  Back-off pulling image "kvaradha/client"
>     Warning  Failed     109s                kubelet, docker-desktop  Error: ImagePullBackOff
>     Normal   Pulling    55s (x4 over 2m1s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Pulling image "kvaradha/client"
>     Normal   Created    54s (x3 over 2m)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Created container client
>     Normal   Pulled     54s (x3 over 2m)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Successfully pulled image "kvaradha/client"
>     Normal   Started    53s (x3 over 2m)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Started container client
>     Warning  BackOff    9s (x7 over 96s)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Back-off restarting failed container`

Built a container with "FROM golang", same end result:

> `test-client-bd4c475d4-cmnd6           1/1     Running            2          30s
>   test-client-bd4c475d4-cmnd6           0/1     Completed          2          31s
>   hello-world-client-77775898c-564lt    0/1     Completed          325        27h
>   test-client-bd4c475d4-cmnd6           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2          44s
>   hello-world-client-77775898c-564lt    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   325        27h`

Comment: Could you please just run the container  `docker run --rm kvaradha/client` to see the error without k8s.

Comment: `kubectl describe po test-client-74cddbb988-rxx8f` might help with debug info. I'd also double-check that your ARCH param matches your worker nodes, and/or try `FROM alpine` or `FROM golang` (The `exec user process caused "exec format error"` error)

Comment: @sfrehse  No errors with docker...  `➜ *docker run --rm kvaradha/client*
2020/02/28 21:25:06 hostname: [::1]:65432 name: H009011
➜ *echo $?*
0`  (Sorry comment formatting is *ugly*)

Comment: @CurtisMattoon  Will try try FROM golang suggestion and get back to you.  For the describe output, looks "normal" to me... ` 
  Normal   Created    54s (x3 over 2m)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Created container client
  Normal   Started    53s (x3 over 2m)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Started container client
  Warning  BackOff    9s (x7 over 96s)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Back-off restarting failed container`

Comment: Your `echo $?` from docker command means the last command was executed without any errors, but your container still running?

Comment: @rabello. That was specific to the experiment of running the container standalone using docker, and the result from the program termination with docker

Answer (score 2):

This is an intended and expected behavior. Kubernetes main job is to ensure that a given application is running at all times. If an application exits (regardless of the exit code), Kubernetes (more specifically the `kubelet` daemon) will assume that the application has crashed and will start it again. Hence it is expected of your application to be a long running process (I.e.: a server).

If your application is meant to run only once and then cleanly exit, a [Kubernetes Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) would be more appropriate instead of a Deployment. That way the pod will run to completion with no `CrashLoopBackOff` errors.

Comment: I understand your comment on the restart behaviour and do get the Job vs Deployment specs.

Comment: Wanted to add, how is the behaviour with dnsutils using shell's "sleep 3600" get treated differently by kubernetes.  That is the crux of what I want to understand.